# How to set up LDAP authentication with Symfony, Docker Compose and Traefik?

Tags: symfony, docker-compose, ldap, traefik, osixia

I'm trying to set up a configuration for my symfony's app using traefik, docker-compose and ldap.

Unfortunately, I can't get my ldap. Is there someone who knows what's happen ?

my security.yaml with the 'my_ldap' provider :

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    hide_user_not_found: false
    
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        # App\Entity\User:
        #     algorithm: auto
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        my_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: 'dc=example,dc=org'
                search_dn: 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org'
                search_password: 'admin'
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: uid
                extra_fields: ['email']
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: my_ldap
            form_login_ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                dn_string: 'dc=example,dc=org'
                query_string: '(&(uid={user_identifier})(memberOf=cn=users,ou=users,dc=example,dc=org))'
                search_dn: 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org'
                search_password: 'admin'
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                provider: my_ldap

            logout:
                path: app_logout

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/home, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
...
```

my service.yaml :

```
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
        arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
        tags:
            - ldap
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
        arguments:
            -   host: localhost
                port: 389
                # encryption: tls
                options:
                    protocol_version: 3
                    referrals: false
```

my docker-compose with osixia's, db, www, traefik images :

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    openldap:
        image: osixia/openldap:latest
        container_name: openldap
        environment:
            - LDAP_LOG_LEVEL=256
            - LDAP_ORGANISATION=Example Inc.
            - LDAP_DOMAIN=example.org
            - LDAP_BASE_DN=cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
            - LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
            - LDAP_CONFIG_PASSWORD=config
            - LDAP_READONLY_USER=false
            - LDAP_RFC2307BIS_SCHEMA=false
            - LDAP_BACKEND=mdb
            - LDAP_TLS=true
            - LDAP_TLS_CRT_FILENAME=ldap.crt
            - LDAP_TLS_KEY_FILENAME=ldap.key
            - LDAP_TLS_DH_PARAM_FILENAME=dhparam.pem
            - LDAP_TLS_CA_CRT_FILENAME=ca.crt
            - LDAP_TLS_ENFORCE=false
            - LDAP_TLS_CIPHER_SUITE=SECURE256:-VERS-SSL3.0
            - LDAP_TLS_VERIFY_CLIENT=demand
            - LDAP_REPLICATION=false
            - KEEP_EXISTING_CONFIG=false
            - LDAP_REMOVE_CONFIG_AFTER_SETUP=true
            - LDAP_SSL_HELPER_PREFIX=ldap
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        volumes:
            - /var/lib/ldap
            - /etc/ldap/slapd.d
            - /container/service/slapd/assets/certs/
        ports:
            - "389:389"
            - "636:636"
        # For replication to work correctly, domainname and hostname must be
        # set correctly so that "hostname"."domainname" equates to the
        # fully-qualified domain name for the host.
        domainname: "example.org"
        hostname: "ldap-server"
        networks:
            - dev
        logging:
            driver: json-file

    phpldapadmin:
        image: osixia/phpldapadmin:latest
        container_name: phpldapadmin
        environment:
            PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS: "openldap"
            PHPLDAPADMIN_HTTPS: "false"
        ports:
          - "8180:80"
        depends_on:
          - openldap
        networks:
            - dev

    db:
        image: mysql
        container_name: db_icu_2
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        networks:
            - dev
        logging:
            driver: json-file

    www:
        build: php_icu_2
        container_name: www_icu_2
        volumes:
            - ./php_icu_2/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
            - ./:/var/www
        restart: always
        labels:
            traefik.http.routers.service1-http.middlewares: https-redirect
            traefik.http.routers.service1-http.rule: Host(`localhost`)
            traefik.http.routers.service1-https.rule: Host(`localhost`)
            traefik.http.routers.service1-http.entrypoints: http
            traefik.http.routers.service1-https.tls: 'true'
            traefik.http.services.icuapp.loadbalancer.server.port: '80'
            traefik.constraint-label: traefik-public
            traefik.http.middlewares.service1-https.redirectscheme.scheme: https
            traefik.docker.network: traefik-public
            traefik.enable: 'true'
            traefik.http.routers.service1-https.entrypoints: https
        networks:
            - dev
        logging:
            driver: json-file

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin_icu_2
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - 8088:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: db
        networks:
            - dev
        logging:
            driver: json-file        

    traefik:
        restart: unless-stopped
        container_name: traefik_icu_2
        image: traefik
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
            - "8080:8080"
        labels:
            - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
            - "traefik.http.routers.service1.entrypoints=web"

        volumes:
            - ./traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
            - ./tls.yml:/etc/traefik/tls.yml
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - certs:/etc/ssl/traefik
        networks:
            - dev
        logging:
            driver: json-file

    reverse-proxy-https-helper:
        image: alpine
        command: sh -c "cd /etc/ssl/traefik
          && wget traefik.me/cert.pem -O cert.pem
          && wget traefik.me/privkey.pem -O privkey.pem"
        volumes:
            - certs:/etc/ssl/traefik
        networks:
            - dev
        logging:
            driver: json-file
             
networks:
    dev:
    openldap:
        driver: overlay

volumes:
    db-data:
    certs:
```

Thanks for your help :)